# What LEI activity should I use? Direct Transfer or Replication?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

What is difference between LEI Direct Transfer and Replication activities?
I'm trying to copy/sync data from DB2 to Notes just one way. Any updates in DB2 should go into Notes.
So what activity should I use.
BTW, Direct Transfer creates duplicate views in Notes db. What could cause that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Either option would work, though if you're looking to "sync" data between the two I'd probably lean to the replication.  I have a client that uses the Direct Transfer to move data from Domino to DB2 and it works fine for them.

Regarding the duplicate issue, it sounds like you're saying duplicate entries (docs) are created in the NSF and not actual Views in the NSF? On the Target Data Options tab for the activity, do you have the Try Update before Insert option checked? That should prevent that if the Target Key Field has a field selected that does not have a value that changes after the entry is created in DB2.

Comment: Thank you @thardenb... As regards duplicates...  It creates design views with the form name (that is defined as target in that activity)... What could cause that issue? Also does Direct Transfer means just sync or it removes entries from DB2? Otherwise what's the difference between Direct Transfer and Replication activities? Thank you